# CAKE and DumpXmlTestDiscovery setting from NUnit test adapter

Tags: nunit, cakebuild

I have solution with unit tests.
I create .runsettings configuration in my project using this and add setting 'DumpXmlTestDiscovery' from this page https://docs.nunit.org/articles/vs-test-adapter/Tips-And-Tricks.html

After local build, I can find dump file in **\bin\Debug\Dump.

I tried to build my solution via CAKE using

```
MSBuild(solution, new MSBuildSettings {
            Verbosity = buildVerbosity,
            Configuration = configuration,
            MaxCpuCount = 0,
            NodeReuse = false,
            ToolVersion = MSBuildToolVersion.VS2019
        });
```

but this dump file didn't create.

Is there a way to get this dump file while running MSBuild in CAKE?

Comment: Just to confirm... the link that you provided shows the usage of `dotnet test`, but in the Cake alias that you are using is for `MSBuild`, so the results will not be the same.  Exactly what comment are you executing when things work?  Once we know that, we should be able to point you are the correct alias to use.